# Why does my formatting break when I change compiler from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, fontspec, font-encodings

I'm writing a document in Overleaf using a document template I've been given, and I need to use the formatting style set out in that template. I've had to change the compiler I'm using from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX so that I can make use of certain linguistic Unicode characters.

The problem I'm having is that changing the compiler seems to have broken the formatting of the template, and I'm not sure how I can fix it.

The only change I made in the preamble to facilitate the new compiler was that I replaced this:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

With this:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\abr{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\og{Noto Sans Ogham}
```

Now my title page has changed, the title is no longer bold or using the correct margin sizes. Chapter titles in the table of contents are all lowercase, and section titles in the main body are lowercase too. Aside from these specific issues, the primary font of the whole document has also clearly changed. These are just the issues I've noticed, I suspect there are more subtle changes I haven't noticed yet.

How can I get it to look like it did with the old compiler?

Here are some pictures for reference.

Before (correct formatting):

[image: original title page]

[image: original table of contents]

[image: original section titles]

After (formatting broken):

[image: broken title page]

[image: broken table of contents]

[image: broken section titles]

EDIT: Adding minimal code to enable recreation of the issue.

The issue should be reproducible just switching between compilers without making any changes to the code below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,headinclude,footinclude]{book}

% document packages



\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \newfontfamily\abr{Noto Serif}
 \newfontfamily\og{Noto Sans Ogham}
\else
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\fi

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./chapters/images/}}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  eulerchapternumbers,
  eulermath,
  subfig,
  beramono,
  pdfspacing,
  floatperchapter,
]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage[  % check the README file about margins
  left=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  top=3cm,
  bottom=3cm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy text, you can remove this

% macro definitions
\newcommand{\figurePath}[1]{figures/#1}

% use one and a half line spacing
\onehalfspacing

% set your title, author and publication date here
\title{Development of Natural Looking Titles and Reports about Nothing; with an Application for Deterring Authorship in Other Word Processors}
\author{Andrew Daly}
\date{\today}

% start the document with the title page
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  % main logo
  \vspace*{3em}
  % main title, author and date
  {\color{darkgray} \Large \bfseries\selectfont Team Report} \\ [5em]
  {\sffamily \bfseries \selectfont \huge \singlespacing \thetitle \par}
  \vspace*{2em}
  {\Large \theauthor} \\ [4em]
  {\textbf \thedate} \\ [4em]
  % teams and members
  \parbox{0.25\textwidth}{
    \centering \color{darkgray}
    \textbf{Team A} \\ Greg Thompson
  }
  \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{
    \centering \color{darkgray}
    \textbf{Team B} \\ John McAvoy \\ Cliodhna Dempsy
  }
  \parbox{0.25\textwidth}{
    \centering \color{darkgray}
    \textbf{Team C} \\ Paul Buttler
  } \\
  \vfill
  % secondary logo and footer

  {\color{darkgray}
  Centre for Mocked Up Team Reviews \\
  College of Teamwork, International University of Jupiter
  }
\end{titlepage}

% the front matter of the document
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Abstract}
This is an abstract, there should be about a paragraph of text here. 
\lipsum[10]
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
Thanks folks!

% these are the included chapters
\mainmatter
\chapter{Review of the Literature}\label{ch:litrev}
\section{All About the Dictionary}
This is some text about a dictionary. \lipsum[5]
\section{Teamwork in the Context of Dictionaries}
It would be difficult to write a dictionary on your own. \lipsum[10]
\section{Another Title I Came Up With}
I'm running out of things to say here. \lipsum[9]
\lipsum[6-8]

\appendices
\chapter{Placeholders}
\section{Unused References}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item List item 1
    \item List item 2
    \item List item 3
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on this site, please give others a better chance to evaluate your problem by providing a full but minimal example they can copy and test as is.

Comment: Additionally, what exactly do you mean by "break formatting"? I see two documents with different fonts, thus different metrics and different line breaks. This is normal when changing fonts. You might even see it when going from a type1 version (pdflatex) to an otf version in lualatex of the same font (lualatex can use both). The metrics are not always the same.

Comment: Hi daleif, I'm working on a minimal example and will add it to my post. What I mean by "break formatting" is that the font has changed without me specifying a new font, the case of chapter titles and section titles changes to lower case without me specifying that the case should be lowercase, and the title changes to not be boldface anymore. Are you saying they'll all change back if I specify an appropriate font?

Comment: You presumably were selecting some 8 bit font family previously and are not selecting similar opentype fonts now but as you have shown no information at all, I doubt anyone can answer. If you select a bold font and no bold is available then you will always get a warning in the log showing the attempted font and the font latex used, but you haven't shown your log either.

Comment: Erh, the default font in latex is not `Noto Serif` or `Noto Sans Ogham` so at least you need to explain how you got those in the `pdflatex` version.

Comment: I've just added enough code above to reproduce the problem. I hope that helps. @daleif I didn't use `Noto Serif` or `Noto Sans Ogham` with `pdfLaTeX`. I only use them with `LuaLaTeX` to show characters which do not display using the default font.

Comment: Please note that your example is not self contained. We do not have those images. IMO they are not needed to dhow your problem anyway.

Comment: Additionally you can use the `iftex` package to get if constructions such that for example `fontenc` is automatically loaded with `pdflatex` and `fontspec` with `lualatex`

Comment: I edited the example (matching @daleif comment)

Comment: latex does warn you: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`TU/iwona/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using \`TU/iwona/m/n' instead on input line 65.`
 that is, it failed to find a bold unicode version of the non standard iwona font family

Comment: I don't seem to be getting that warning. In any case, I don't think I need to use an if construction because I'll only be using `LuaLaTeX`, so the `iftex` solution is probably unnecessary. It's interesting to know it's there to be used, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the classicthesis and arsclassica packages are not really set up for Unicode fonts, and LaTeX does warn you that sans serif is not working,

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/iwona/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 65.


(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg
)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/iwona/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/iwona/m/n' instead on input line 65.
```

That is the first one saying it can't find iwona so will use latin modern, then the second one saying it can't find bold.

However you can use fontspec to set the sans serif to the OpenType version of iwona then it does set up bold as well

Output from lualatex:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,headinclude,footinclude]{book}

% document packages



\usepackage{iftex}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./chapters/images/}}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[
  eulerchapternumbers,
  eulermath,
  subfig,
  beramono,
  pdfspacing,
  floatperchapter,
]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}


\iftutex
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \newfontfamily\abr{Noto Serif}
 \newfontfamily\og{Noto Sans Ogham}
 \setsansfont{iwona}
\else
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\fi
```

---

that fixes the main issue, although arsclassica still has some low level code such as

```
%************************************************************
% Chapter numbers
%************************************************************
\let\chapterNumber\undefined
\ifct@eulerchapternumbers
\newfont{\chapterNumber}{eurb10 scaled 5000}%
\else
\newfont{\chapterNumber}{pplr9d scaled 5000}%
\fi
```

which is using internal names and scaling commands to force legacy 8bit fonts, you probably should use the `\iftutex` block in the preamble above to use fontspec defined fonts for `\chapterNumber` as well.

Comment: Possibly, but I've just tested this out to see if it would fix the title, or the lowercase issues, and it doesn't seem to have done anything at all. Does it solve the issue with the output when you run it?

Comment: @AdeDoyle I added an image of the lualatex output. If you are not getting small caps headings lualatex will be showing you a font warning about iwona/sc, what does it say?

Comment: did you move the iftutex block after arsclassica? @AdeDoyle

Comment: That's it, I hadn't moved it after `arsaclassica`. Thank you. I wonder if I could just remove `arsaclassica`, or if there's some alternative for use with `LuaLaTeX`. I can try defining my own font for `\chapterNumber`, as you suggested, but I'm not sure what the condition is in `\ifct@eulerchapternumbers` above, so I can't copy it.

Comment: @AdeDoyle I didn't check the code but I assume it is just true if you used the option `eulerchapternumbers` which you have done